# regex for multiple type os logs

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I need extract Ip for logs and try search some example. For others lines log get several examples, but I am unable to apply to this case.

I'm bad programmer, and worse with regex. Try http://rubular.com but not I do not get the expression

```
Apr-28-16 04:16:33 [SSL-out] 111.111.111.111 warning: SMTP authentication failed;
Apr-28-16 04:28:35 222.222.222.222 warning: SMTP authentication failed;
```

I need extract IP when condition it's SMTP authentication failed with regex expression perl based, on bash script CSf firewall

Comment: The problem is we don't have a pattern of fixed format. This is evident from your example itself

Comment: @Borodin - That edit was completely inappropriate. Please don't do that again.

Comment: @BradLarson: Please explain yourself. Are you really saying that the original subject line that you have reverted to is better? I used the OP's own words, and I can see nothing in the guidelines that countermands my edit. What is it exactly that I must never do again?

Comment: @Borodin - Perhaps you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @BradLarson: Your implication is clearly that my edit was "nasty", which wasn't my intention at all. I apologise to anyone—particularly the OP—whom I may have upset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every line you want to capture has "SMTP authentication failed", this should do the trick. It captures the IP (in a rudimentary fashion) and puts it into `$1` if there's an IP followed later by "SMTP authentication failed".

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>){
    if (/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(?=.*?SMTP\s+authentication\s+failed)/){
        print "$1\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
Apr-28-16 04:16:33 [SSL-out] 111.111.111.111 warning: SMTP authentication failed;
Apr-28-16 04:16:33 [SSL-out] 111.111.111.112 warning: SMTP authentication success;
Apr-28-16 04:16:33 [SSL-out] 111.111.111.113 warning: SMTP authentication failed;
Apr-28-16 04:28:35 222.222.222.222 warning: SMTP authentication failed;
```

Output:

```
111.111.111.111
111.111.111.113
222.222.222.222
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply @stevieb  Work fine and I can apply to more scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern fetches IP adresses which are followed by 'SMTP authentication failed' and outputs them if a match is found.
The IP pattern is not perfect (as it allows e.g. `123.456.000.999`), but it's a good start.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while(my $line = <DATA>) {
    if (my ($ip) = ($line=~/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*SMTP authentication failed/)) {
        print "faulty ip=$ip\n";
    } 
}

__DATA__
Apr-28-16 04:16:33 [SSL-out] 111.111.111.111 warning: SMTP authentication failed;
Apr-28-16 04:28:35 222.222.222.222 warning: SMTP authentication failed;
```

Output:

```
faulty ip=111.111.111.111
faulty ip=222.222.222.222
```